# Python V2 event grid output doesn't show on azure portal, while just triggers show (using microsoft code and not seeing any errors)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventgrid

I'm using Python V2 model event grid trigger and output binding. I'm using microsoft example code provided. I'm deploying using git action and local-exe.
I tried deploying just the trigger and it successfully got deployed and was able to see it on the azure portal.
When I tried deploying with output to write to a custom topic. In git actions it successfully deployed without any errors but i dont see it on azure portal and stopped being triggered.

my requiremnets.txt just has azure-functions

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import datetime


@app.function_name(name="eventGridTrigger")
@app.route(route="eventgrid_output")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent, 
         outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.log("eventGridEvent: ", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="test-id",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

to be able to see it and to get triggered and forward the event to the custom topic

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python) and implemented output binding with the below code:

**Code Snippet:**

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="eventgridout")
@app.event_grid_trigger(arg_name="eventGridEvent")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent, 
         outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.info("eventGridEvent: %s", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="123",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "MyEventGridTopicUriSetting":"<Topic_Endpoint_Uri>",
    "MyEventGridTopicKeySetting":"<Topic_access_key>"
  }
}
```

- Created an Event Grid Topic and configured the subscription with Function app endpoint.

[image]

- Add the settings in `Environment Variables=>Application Settings` in the function app:

```
1. MyEventGridTopicUriSetting="<Topic_Endpoint_Uri>"
2. MyEventGridTopicKeySetting="<Topic_access_key>"
```

[image]

- Deployed the Function to Azure:

[image]

[image]

- Able to trigger the function successfully:

[image]

[image]

- Configured EventHub to send the events to Storage Account Queue.

[image]

Comment: were you able to get it working with managed identity

Comment: No, I didn't try with managed identity as you didn't mention about it in your ask.

Comment: i'm having trouble on what to put for the topic_key_setting  when managed identity
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")

Comment: Did you check this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python#identity-based-authentication)?

Comment: Yes, it only shows for python v1. For v2, the MSDOC doesn't mention what should be the value here topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting" and i can't remove topic_key_setting from the event_grid_output it expects it. Also with None throws an error so i'm wondering if python v2 even supports managed identity

Comment: You have to use the connection property instead of `topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting"` and `topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting"` in the code.